# How to do I run this .exe file on RPi

Tags: raspberry-pi

Hi I am currently having an issue trying to run a .exe file in raspberry pi using mono. The .exe file is using a library called `supersimpletcp` which I downloaded from visual studios. Once I have successfully run the application, I then transfer the .exe file from my computer to the raspberry pi running on Raspbian and when I try to run it it shows me this.

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 
'LastTCPWinform.Form1:client' (0) due to: Could not load file or assembly 
'SimpleTcp, Version=2.3.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of 
its dependencies.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load 
type of field 'LastTCPWinform.Form1:client' (0) due to: Could not load file 
or assembly 'SimpleTcp, Version=2.3.0.2, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess that your computer is running on Intel or AMD processor and you want to run an executable for those processors onto a Raspberry Pi card running on ARM processor?

Comment: @RachidK. this does appear to be the case

Comment: You need to compile with a compiler generating ARM code. Either you have a compiler installed on your Raspberry Pi and you compile on it or you install a cross-compiler on your host PC. Raspberry's web site provides instructions to make it.

Comment: @RachidK. This appears to be a .NET executable, so this should be fine to run on ARM. Is the SimpleTcp library also a C# library or is it C++ or managed C++?

Comment: i think box86 is what you need